# How would you get the index of the lowest value in an int array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Considering that this is a very basic task, I could not think of an appropriately easy way to do it. How would you get the index of the lowest value in an int array? Using Linq/MoreLinq is possible. I could not find a reasonable one-liner so far.

Comment: Can there be duplicate numbers in the array, and in which case, which index do you want to show if there are two of the lowest number?

Comment: @Paddy Yes duplicates are possible. Any of these is fine to be returned, though a (any) consistent behavior would be appreciated (e.g. always the last).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you mention MoreLinq, how about:

```
int[] array = ..

// Will throw if the array is empty.
// If there are duplicate minimum values, the one with the smaller
// index will be chosen.
int minIndex = array.AsSmartEnumerable()
                    .MinBy(entry => entry.Value)
                    .Index;
```

Another alternative:

```
// Will throw if the array is empty.
// Requires two passes over the array. 
int minIndex = Array.IndexOf(array, array.Min());
```

You could of course write your own extension-method:

```
// Returns last index of the value that is the minimum.
public static int IndexOfMin(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
   if(source == null)
     throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

   int minValue = int.MaxValue;
   int minIndex = -1;
   int index = -1;

   foreach(int num in source)
   {
      index++;

      if(num <= minValue)
      {
         minValue = num;
         minIndex = index;
      }
   }

   if(index == -1)
     throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence was empty");

   return minIndex;
}
```

With some effort, you can generalize this to any type by accepting an `IComparer<T>`, defaulting to `Comparer<T>.Default`.

Comment: Why did you chose foreach over for in the extension method?

Comment: In general, sequences cannot be accessed by index. Using a `foreach`  is the normal way to iterate an arbitrary sequence. You *could* get the enumerator and then use a `for` loop, but that would look quite messy. If you really do need the enumerator, a `while` loop is far more common. In this case, neither is necessary.

Comment: Oops, yes, I was accidentally thinking of `source` as an array.

Comment: @mafutrct: Actually, `foreach` over an *array* is optimized. It should produce identical IL to the equivalent `for` loop.

Comment: @Ani: As far as I'm aware -- and I'm not an expert -- the optimisation of `foreach` over an array is done by the compiler, not the jitter, which means that it only happens when the *compile-time type* is an array, whereas the compile-time type of your `source` parameter is `IEnumerable<>`. (Of course, using `foreach` over an array typed as `IEnumerable<>` will still be lightning-fast, just maybe not quite as fast as the optimised version.)

Comment: @LukeH: Yes, I do believe you're right. That is another matter though; I brought this up because mafutrct seemed to suggest that the enumeration should look different (for-loop) if the parameter were typed to `int[]`. Now, if we had an overload of this method with identical code that accepted an `int[]`, *that* would *probably* bring performance improvements for an array.

Comment: On another note, I believe the optimization the CLR brings to the table is eliminating array-bound checking for `for(i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)a[i].Something();`, which is something like what the C# compiler produces for a `foreach` over an array.

Answer (score 17):

LINQ probably isn't the best solution for this problem, but here's another variation that is O(n). It doesn't sort and only traverses the array once.

```
var arr = new int[] { 3, 1, 0, 5 };
int pos = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => (arr[a] < arr[b]) ? a : b); // returns 2
```

**Update:** Answering the original question directly, this is how I would do it:

```
var arr = new int[] { 3, 1, 0, 5 };
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] < arr[pos]) { pos = i; }
}
// pos == 2
```

No, it doesn't use LINQ. Yes, it is more than one line. But it is really simple and really fast. Make it into a tiny little method and call it from anywhere on a single line: `pos = FindMinIndex(arr);`

Comment: This should be the answer. Much faster and simpler!

Comment: @RMalke How much faster?

Comment: I didn't measure, but I was Select((x, i)=>...).OrderBy(...).First(...) and calling it exact times 15257190400. I t was significantly faster

Answer (score 7):

Not very memory friendly, but...

```
array.Select((n, i) => new { index = i, value = n })
     .OrderBy(item => item.value)
     .First().index
```

Comment: You could also replace the OrderBy/First with MinBy.

Comment: @mafutrct: yep if you have MoreLinq, which you do but I don't :)

Answer (score 4):

It's ugly but it only needs a single pass through the sequence and only uses built-in framework methods:

```
int index = yourArray.Select((x, i) => new { Val = x, Idx = i })
                     .Aggregate(new { Val = -1, Idx = -1 },
                                (a, x) => (x.Idx == 0 || x.Val < a.Val) ? x : a,
                                x => x.Idx);
```

And, of course, you can write a general-purpose extension method:

```
int index = yourArray.MinIndex();

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static int MinIndex<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        if (comparer == null)
            comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                return -1;    // or maybe throw InvalidOperationException

            int minIndex = 0;
            T minValue = enumerator.Current;

            int index = 0;
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                index++;
                if (comparer.Compare(enumerator.Current, minValue) < 0)
                {
                    minIndex = index;
                    minValue = enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
            return minIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one is probably an horror in terms of performances ;)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
int[] data = new []{ 10, 2, 3, 4, 2 };
var index = data
  .Select((v, i) =>new {Index = i, Val = v})
  .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Val == data.Min()).Index; // 1
```

But be careful, because you remember that you will get an exception if the array is null

Comment: Explain your answer my dude

Comment: I hope the additional data in the answer will be enough to understand the answer.

Comment: This code will go through the values too many times. Its fine for 5 numbers, less so for 5_000_000. Once for Select, once for FirstOrDefault, per execution of FirstOrDefault it will iterate over everything to find the Min.