# Minimum funcion doesn't work as it should

Tags: c#

I've written this code with Visual studio c# WindowsForms but it doesn't work as it should.
On my Form1:

```
private void btnVisualizzaPrezzoMin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listView1.Items.Clear();
   int i = 0;    
   while (i < num)     
   {
       if (eleMutui[i].Durata <= int.Parse(txtDurata2.Text) && eleMutui[i].Durata >= int.Parse(txtDurata1.Text))
       {
           int Min = Funzioni.ImportoMin(eleMutui, num);
           ListViewItem Nuovariga = default(ListViewItem);          
           Nuovariga = new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
                eleMutui[Min].Codice.ToString(),
                eleMutui[Min].Nome,
                eleMutui[Min].Provincia,
                eleMutui[Min].DataPartenza.ToString(),
                eleMutui[Min].Importo.ToString(),
                eleMutui[Min].Durata.ToString() 
             });

         listView1.Items.Add(Nuovariga);

    }
    i++;
}
```

And the Minimum funcion is:

```
public static int ImportoMin(Mutui[] ele, int n)
{
    int x = 0;
    decimal MinimoImporto = default(int);
    while (x < n)
    {
        if (ele[x].Importo < MinimoImporto)
        {
            MinimoImporto = ele[x].Importo;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return decimal.ToInt32(MinimoImporto);
}
```

Can you help me? I have to do: given by the user a duration interval (ex. between 60 and 120 months), display all the data of the
loan of a lower amount that has a duration in the indicated range.
Thank you!!

Comment: How should it work? What is it doing instead?

Comment: You do realize that `default(int)` is zero.  You should initialize the min to either the first value or to a Max.  Alternatively you can use Linq's `Min` method instead.

Comment: What's `num`? I don't see it's declaration.

Comment: On top of initializing the min to 0 you also seem to want the index of the min value and not the actual min value, so you'd need to keep track of the index as well and return that instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204169/how-would-you-get-the-index-of-the-lowest-value-in-an-int-array

Answer (score 0):

In your function `ImportoMin`, instead of using a while loop, you should probably do a `for` loop instead.

```
public static int ImportoMin(Mutui[] ele)
   {
    // I'd return -1 or something to indicate something is wrong
    if(ele.Count == 0) return -1;
    decimal MinimoImporto = int.MaxValue;

    for(int i = 1; i < ele.Length; i++)
    {
      if( ele[i].Importo < MinimoImporto)
      MinimoImporto = ele[i].Importo;
    }

    return MinimoImporto;
}
```

In your funciton, you initialize your min to be zero and unless everything else is negative, it will return zero every time.

Edit: This function will return the minimum value in the array, however you can refer to juharr's answer if you're looking for the index.

Comment: If you look carefully you'll see that the OP is actually trying to get the index with the minimum value.

Comment: Yeah, I had to reread the question a few times to try and see what he was attempting to do. The logic of what he was attempting vs what he asked kind of threw me off. You’re correct.

Comment: It threw me off to begin with too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your method is that you initialize the min value to zero.  Meaning that if all the values in the array are greater than zero then it's going to return zero instead of the actual min.  The second issue is that you seem to want the index of the minimum value but you don't keep track of the index and instead return either 0 or the actual min in the array when it's negative (if that's possible).  One option is to use MoreLinq's `MinBy` instead.

```
var itemWithMinImporto = eleMutui.MinBy(x => x.Importto);
```

Or you can do that with Linq

```
var itemWithMinImporto = eleMutui.OrderBy(x=>x.Importto).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you can find the index with a normal for loop

```
int minIndex = -1;
decimal minValue = decimal.MaxValue;
for(int i = 0; i < eleMutui.Length; i++)
{
    if(item[i].Importto < minValue)
    {
        minValue = item[i].Importto;
        minIndex = i;
    }
}

return minIndex;
```

Note that it's not clear if `n` is the actual length of the array or not.  If not the above code can be altered to take that into account by using `Take(n)` for the MoreLinq and Linq solutions or just doing `i < n` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand why you use `n` in `ImportoMin()`, when you are basically just looping though the `[]`. (That is if `n` is supposed to be the length of the `[]`, but I don't see where `num` is declared.)

To continue with your format, you can do something like this:

```
public static int ImportoMin(Mutui[] ele)
{
    decimal MinimoImporto = int.MaxValue;
    for(int x = 0; x < ele.length; x++)
    {
       if (ele[x].Importo < MinimoImporto)
       {
           MinimoImporto = ele[x].Importo;
       }
    }
    return decimal.ToInt32(MinimoImporto);
}
```

Comment: Actually the OP is trying to get the index with the minimum value.