# C# Find the row in a list whose price is closest to 0

Tags: c#

I have a clump of data pulled from an SQL database and stored inside a list:

[image: Data list]

as you can see in the image there are a few data columns. What I'm trying to do is out of the 69 items I want to find the one whose Rate_Price is closest to 0. It can be a negative or a positive.

Current Code:
`var data = _rateManager.Get30Year("30-Year Fixed Rate");`

Comment: Please share the code not screenshot.

Comment: Please show your effort so far

Comment: hint : you want the min of the abs value

Comment: @Sham i dont have any code the only code i have the code to get the data. I cant seem to wrap my head around the issue.

Comment: You can sort based on the abs of the rate_price, and then take top x, rows, or you can take every row where rate_price >= your limit.

Comment: I am not sure what the full process is, but using absolute value Math.Abs(Rate_Price) and then compare.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204169/how-would-you-get-the-index-of-the-lowest-value-in-an-int-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a console app that adds a load of -ive and +ive integers randomly to a list and then sorts the list producing the one that's closest to 0:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        var values = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            values.Add(random.Next(-1000, 1000));
        }

        foreach (var item in values.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item}, ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The closest to 0 therefore is:");
        Console.WriteLine(values.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i)).First());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The key bit here is:

```
values.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i)).First()
```

Or in case of your example:

```
data.OrderBy(i => Math.Abs(i.Rate_Price)).First();
```

Or

```
data.First(i => Math.Abs(i.Rate_Price));
```

That said in your example i am guessing all Rate_Price will be a positive number so to get the first all you need is:

```
data.OrderBy(i => i.Rate_Price).First();
```

Comment: the orderby is perfect however the rate_price can be a negative

Comment: Therefore `data.First(i => Math.Abs(i.Rate_Price));`

Comment: This is getting very close however i dont need the first() i need to value thats closest to 0. So current after your order its ordering them as 0.053, 0.037, -0.010. The -0.010 is closest to 0.

Comment: The code above gives the first lowest data item in the array, use `data.First(i => Math.Abs(i.Rate_Price)).Rate_Price` to get the `Rate_Price`

Answer (score 1):

in sql (if you can)

```
select * from thingies order by (abs(rate)) asc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SQL, try `select * from thingies where RATE_PRICE = (select MIN(RATE_PRICE) from thingies where RATE_PRICE > 0`